# Image meta tag not correctly picked up by Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, share, facebook-opengraph

We are running into a strange problem when Facebook crawles our pages.

When we want to share the page with its not showing the appropriate thumbnail image. Running the page through the Facebook debugger produces the following error:
[image]

But if you look in the source we have the correct image selected in the og:image tag.
Example URL: https://www.virres.com/clients/virres/test-vincent5.html  (the share buttons are located on the top right)

When you try to solve this, please dont click the "Rescrape" button because it will fix the individual issue but not the problem.
Since this is an automated page, we cannot click the Rescrape button for each generated page(as suggested in other solutions).

I hope someone can see whats wrong here. Been puzzling at it for days on end now.

Its not a duplicate of [Facebook preview image not showing for wordpress blog post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43896968/facebook-preview-image-not-showing-for-wordpress-blog-post) because even after creating an iframe with src of the Facebook debugger it didnt read the og:image propery properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook preview image not showing for wordpress blog post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43896968/facebook-preview-image-not-showing-for-wordpress-blog-post)

Comment: Your example URL does not contain a single `og:...` meta tag; at least not when I view the source code in my browser. Did you implement anything to serve them to the FB scraper only ...?

Comment: Typo: The URL should be https://www.virres.com/clients/virres/test-vincent5.html

Comment: You still don't have any meta tags on that page.